# You don't have permission to access / on this server for HTTPS URL

Tags: debian, https, owncloud

I have installed ownCloud on Debian OS. It works with HTTP  but not with HTTPS.

When an HTTPS URL is opened it throws this error:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

HTTP Server at 144.24.200.145 Port 443.

Comment: You need to provide your configuration to see why it isn't working. Logs are useful as well.

Comment: Post your logs and any apache configuration files you've edited

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to solve your problem but still there is some suggestion that you might try.

- Your `Document root` or the folder which you trying to access does not allow access a`pache/httpd` user to access it.
- if you are using `.htaccess` then make sure all rules inside it are correct.
- Check your `httpd configuration`. There may be some error.

Comment: When i use the  https:url.com:7443 it works, but when i try with https:url.com   403 forbidden  page.  how to fix this?

Comment: BY default https listen to 443, And it seems your https run on 7443.check that out.